# Import PyCharm Settings From Command Line

Tags: pycharm

I am trying to setup a script which gets all of the packages we use and setup a basic environment for new employees to get up and going with quickly. I am wondering if there is a way to import pycharm settings from the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The settings jar is simply a .zip archive containing some of the files from the PyCharm settings directory. To import the settings from the command line, simply unpack the .jar file to the settings directory. (The path to the directory depends on the OS you're using, and you didn't specify which one it is.)